# Access a Kotlin Outer class using the inner object from somewhere else

Tags: kotlin

I have the following setup:

```kotlin
class A {
    fun runA() {

    }
    inner class B {
        fun runB() { // Proxy method for runA()
            runA() // its okay to call it here
        }
    }
}

fun test() {
    val obj = A().B()
    obj.runA() // how to call this one??
    obj.runB() // i do not want to add a proxy method for everything in A
}
```

Is there any way to call `runA()` when I only have the B object?
Every instance of B is always coupled to an instance of A, so it should theoretically be possible (and as I am able to call runA() from within B proves that)

Best solution that I currently have is providing a accessor of A within B like so:

```kotlin
    inner class B {
        fun a(): A = this@A
        fun runB() {
            runA()
        }
    }
```

and then call it like `obj.a().runA()`

Would be nice if I could just directly call `obj.runA()`, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be technically possible other than the compiler not allowing it.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Seems like a design issue if you have an instance of B without access to the owning A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` is not `A`. The compiler gives `B` a private reference to his own `A`, because he needs it to execute `runA`. But it is private, doesn't mean that you can access from there. You can just write `runA` and it works inside `runB` because an inner class has all the members of the parent class in scope, kind of like when you use a closure. See the analogy with this example:

```
class A {
    fun runA() {

    }
    fun B {
        {
            runA() // its okay to call it here
        }
    }
}

fun test() {
    val obj = A().B()
    obj()
}
```

Similarly to what you saw with the inner class, inside the closure object created when you call the member `B()` you can access to all variables in scope (including the instance of `A` that was used to invoke `B()`).

If you want an object `B` that has all the members of `A` you should probably have a look at inheritance instead of inner classes. Or expose an accessor to `A` instance like you did.